# While passing multiple args as parameters to web method, "No webservice found at" message is thrown

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery, webmethod

Below is the web method which I need to access using ajax.:

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string CallConfiguredWebService(String projectID,String workType,String Page,String Action,String webServiceName,Object[] arguments)
        {}
```

I try to access it from script using the below code.

```
var args = [2];
            args[0] = "Hai";
            args[1] = "Saranya!!";

            $.ajax({
                url: "../../Services/ValidationService.asmx/CallConfiguredWebService?",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ projectID: '302',workType: 'LFAT',Page: 'Create', Action: 'Create', webServiceName: 'WebService195174',arguments: args}),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: fnsuccesscallback,
                error: fnerrorcallback
            });
```

I am getting the following error:

`500 - Internal server error No service found at /Services/ValidationService.asmx`.

I am pretty sure that the url is correct.

I understood from similar posts that it might be because of the parameter mismatch in the ajax call.

I am unable to sort out what is the exact mistake in my code.

Tried using `JSON.stringify` also.

Pls help with your expertise.

**Update:**

The ajax call started working after redeploying the web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call started working after redeploying the web application, without making any changes to the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your url from "../../Services/ValidationService.asmx/CallConfiguredWebService" to "/Services/ValidationService.asmx/CallConfiguredWebService" as long as the services directory is at the root for the web app. You should never use "../" a simple "/" will resolve any url starting at the root of the website